# dynamic Accordion post and answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have this fiddle

### http://jsfiddle.net/nesreen/m5TMF/763/

```
$("#AddansId").click(function(){
//get the parent of the div with id(Collapse+x)
// to abend the data content of the textarea beside the word
//Account Registeration at PrepBootstrap
});
```

I can create a dynamic accordion with button 
inside each accordion I need to make another textarea and button to add another texts in the same collapse 
but I face the problem of how can I get the parent of the button in each time even if the parent id is dynamic also

Comment: Your question is unclear.. Could you please elaborate the problem you are facing step by step??

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/sjd6LLrs/#&togetherjs=6RkVBqn8ha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's  see. A few steps to take here:

- First you need to bind the click a bit differently(**[event
  delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**) in this case because you want to click on dinamically
  added elements
- Second, we get the parent id using `closest()` method and `attr('id')`
- For getting the `textarea` value you can use
  `$(this).parent().prev().find('textarea').val()`
- and then use `append()` method to append the text next to the word you want and finally use `$(this).closest('.container').append(answer);` to add the textbefore the word(this was a bit unclear so I added it before `Account Registeration at PrepBootstrap`. I hope that is what you meant)

```js
var x = 1;
$(document).on('click', "#AddansId", function() {
  var idOfParent = $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').attr('id');
  //console.log(idOfParent);
  var answer = $(this).parent().prev().find('textarea').val();
  $(this).closest('.container').append(answer);
});

$(document).on('click', '#AddQuestId', function() {
  x = x + 1;
  $("#accordion").append('<div class="panel panel-default">' +
    '<div class="panel-heading">' +
    '<h4 class="panel-title"> ' +
    '<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse' + x + '">' + $("#comment").val() + '</a>  </h4>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id="collapse' + x + '" class="panel-collapse collapse in">' +
    '<div class="panel-body">' +
    '<div class="container">  ' +
    ' <form>' +
    '<div class="form-group" >' +
    '<label for="comment">answer:</label>' +
    '<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="answer' + x + '"></textarea> ' +
    '  </div>' +
    ' <div style="float: right;"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="answer" id="AddansId"></div>' +

    '</form>' +
    '</div>' +
    'Account registration at <strong>PrepBootstrap</strong>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</h4>' +
    '</div>');
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Question" id="AddQuestId"></div>

  </form>
</div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
</div>
```